# How can I resolve my circular dependencies in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependencies

I have two projects in Asp.Net MVC 3. My 1st project(p1) is having a Controllers and Action Views. I have to filter this in my 2nd(p2) project using Aciton FilterProviders in mvc.

And also I need the class which can Filter My action. I had Implemented up to this. But now my need that I need the specific response to the project p1 from p2. So that according this response i have to display views.

So my dependence becomes like

p2->p1 ( p2 Uses Action Filter from p1)
p1->p2 ( p1 uses response from p2)

How can i resolve this?
Please advice me.

Comment: Can you provide your classes implementation cone from both projects (simplified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a strict layer architecture the layer at low level can only get services from higher layers in your case if `p1` uses `p2` then p2 has to use `p3` or some other service layer which is above it ...

> p3->p2->p1

see also

[How to break apart layers in a strict-layered architecture and promote modularity without causing unnecessary redundancy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182034/how-to-break-apart-layers-in-a-strict-layered-architecture-and-promote-modularit)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_layers_in_an_information_system_logical_architecture